What should I get paid for if I can't work due to circumstances outside of my control?
I just started working for a California-based company, as an employee.
They flew me to Oklahoma to install some equipment. However, one of the two trucks with required equipment broke down and didn't arrive on time.
Now the venue will not let us install because they have an event going on for the next 2 days. This means I will be in Oklahoma for 2 days without working.
Should I expect to be paid at least half time? Full time?

Did you talk to your boss/Supervisor? They should let you know what is happening.

Have a quick think before phoning the boss - what else can you do with your time?  Is there some online training you can work through to help look "invested" ?  Is there any other site in Oklahoma you can visit to meet other employees/customers ?

Are you hourly or salary?  I would be expected to be paid for at least 40 hours' worth of work if hourly.  If I was salary, I would expect to be paid my salary.  Is there other work, like training, you can do while you wait?

Like stated in the comments, you are an employee.
The agenda isn't yours, the issues aren't yours.
Be sure to document the impediments.

Document also means escalate immediately. The moment you face a problem which you cannot fix yourself (which you are facing now), you need to tell your boss. They might have a suggestions (or they call the customers boss, etc)

Double Amen to escalate immediate. Everything in business is about removing uncertainty, that means communication.

+1 to this answer and to lalala's comment, but I'd like to emphasize that even if you were to completely drop the ball and fail to escalate, you should still get paid. You might get in trouble for failing to escalate. But "in trouble" should take the form of a reprimand or something, not the form of arbitrarily withholding pay!

Not sure about US, but in most countries, if you are an employee, and sent on a mission, you are paid (including all bonuses for not being able to come home at night, and all "normal" expenses covered), even if there is no work to be done.
I would, however, send an email to your manager stating that you can't do any work for reasons out of your control (so they can't say they don't know), ask for confirmation that you should stay where you are (maybe they prefer to get you back home, or help out somewhere else).
Also ask if there is anything useful you can perform from where you are: the company still have a right to your time if they choose so. Given the short description of your job, they might tell you there is nothing to do, but maybe there are some things you can prepare, or they want you to try negotiating access, or they want you to read some documentation, or to do some packing lists for the next job, ...
So show them you are still willing to work if they want to, and they will have no reason not to pay you.
If you show no initiative to try to get alternative instructions, it might seem like you're trying to avoid working.

"I would, however, send an email to your manager stating that you can't do any work for reasons out of your control" No, call your manager. On the phone. An employee "fiddling thumbs" because they cannot do the work they were sent to do is definitely urgent enough to warrant a phone call. Otherwise, good answer.

good point to ALSO call your manager. I would still send an email to get some written trail.

@Sandro: You typically send the e-mail after the call, with a summary of the situation, decisions taken, etc... this way you leave a trace of what was agreed on the phone.

When writing the message, I assumed OP already called the manager (because for me it seems so obvious), but yes, if OP hasn't done the call yet (and the message doesn't say he has), then starting with a call, and then the email as a summary is indeed the right order

@Heinzi: Do both. The phone call to show you're taking it seriously, and then a follow-up email to document whatever was said on the phone.

@MatthieuM. That depends on the culture of the company. You may be surprised to hear that some teams/managers find it strange for you to be so aware of keeping paper trails. But it's common. If you email first -- nothing prevents you from being brief -- and then phone, you get a paper trail without appearing deliberate about it.

@Argyll: Even in the absence of "paper trail", I generally find it valuable to send minutes after a meeting, and a call is a form of meeting. It helps ensuring that everyone is on the same page, and it's not out of the ordinary to get a reply correcting a point or two (specifying, loosening, outright contradicting, ...).

Since you are where you were sent, and turned up willing to work, they have to pay you. What can the company do if they don't like it?
They can send you a flight ticket to return home earlier. They can ask you to do some paperwork in your hotel room, that never gets done otherwise. They might have another customer nearby, who is supposed to get help with their equipment next month, and rearrange to move that visit forward so you can do it.

Okie here. With my employer, I'd get paid a normal 8 hour day for that. In fact, any day on travel is automatically at least an 8 hour day. If there's no other charge code to use, we have one specifically for "Travel" that's used while on planes and in airports and whatnot. Your company has to have policies for this, even if you're not acquainted with them (yet). Downtime seems like a good time to ring up your supervisor and learn what the policy is.
I'm a full-time employee though. If you're part time, I don't know how that works. I can't imagine they thought they'd be expecting someone sent to site on an install job to be working part-time though. Travel is expensive, so the bias would be to not want you there any longer than necessary, which probably means overtime, not part time.
I have seen this happen. A former employer had a marine Helicopter they maintain at Kirtland AFB. On occasion you (the maintainer) would come in and be told by guys with guns that the sim was "undergoing maintenance." Then you'd go hit the hotel bar, turn on CNN, and see why they really won't let you use it today. 8 hours. My current employer has install sites in 3rd world countries with unreliable power grids. If we can't get 8 hours of power during our window, that's not our fault. 8 hours.

BTW, if you're looking for ideas for things to do in OK with the spare time, hit me up. Unless you are in Altus. Can't help you there, buddy.

Usually it depends on your contract and location, but as an employee,
when on assignment away from home,
you should be paid your regular daily salary plus per-diem to cover out of town expenses

Quite frequently, companies have travel contracts that will allow them to alter your flight plans and hotel reservations at a shorter notice than you could when traveling on your own.  They also may not mind paying the penalties if it will get you back to the office and working sooner.  Check if they can change your flight back home to sooner.
